# Creating array of arrays different behavior

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have found that these two different methods of creating an array of arrays produce different behaviors:

```
// Method 1
for (var arr1 = []; arr.push([]) < len;) {}

// Method 2
var arr2 = new Array(len).fill([])
```

The arrays created look the same in the console, however they behave differently in my code. What could be causing this?

Comment: *"however they behave differently in my code"* - how so?

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that in the 1st method each index points to a different array, while in the `Array#fill` all indexes point to the same array.

Note: the 1st method will not create an array of arrays

```js
var len = 3;
var arr1 = [];

// Method 1
for (var arr1 = []; arr1.push([]) < len;) {} // new sub array is pushed into arr1

// Method 2
var arr2 = new Array(len).fill([]) // each place in the array is filled with a reference to the same array 

arr1[0].push(1); // push to the 1st element of arr1
arr2[0].push(1); // push to the 1st element of arr2

console.log('arr1: ', JSON.stringify(arr1)); // only the 1st sub array contains 1
console.log('arr2: ', JSON.stringify(arr2)); // all sub arrays contain 1
```

Comment: Interesting. I did some googling, and found this: https://chrisrng.svbtle.com/es6-array-prototype-fill

Answer (score 1):

**Update: While the answer below is technically accurate, and is another difference between the two methods, @Ori Drori's answer is almost certainly what the OP is looking for.**

I'll take a stab at this, but more context would be helpful.

In common practice, these two statements typically behave the same, but there is a key difference - when you use the `new` keyword, the Javascript interpreter calls the Array constructor.

If you were to overwrite the Array constructor, this would only apply to `arr2` which was defined with the new keyword. `arr1` created with the array literal would still be a Javascript array.

As an example, let's say I wrote the following code:

```
function Array() {
}
```

Method 1 would still work, but Method 2 would return a TypeError indicating that fill is not a function.

Interestingly, using the Array literal (Method 1) still calls the Array constructor, so if I did a `console.log("test");` within the Array construction this would still be printed to the console when using either method. BUT, when the Array literal (Method 1) is used, the object itself still remains a standard Javascript array even if the Array constructor is overwritten.